# Background Color Error

Tags: css, background, lightbox

> So I am attempting to make a really simple lightbox that I can use for something, however for whatever reason the div thats supposed to darken the background is canceling out any background attribute.

HTML

```
<div class="zoom-placeholder">
    <div class="zoom-container">
        <img class="zoom" src="image.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.zoom {
    margin: 1em 0em; padding: 1em;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom-width: 2px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.075) 0px 2px 3px, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 0px 25px;
    user-select: none;
    user-drag: none;
}
.zoom-container, .zoom-placeholder {display:table-cell}
.zoom-container.open {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    top: 0px; bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px; right: 0px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0,0.5); /* <--- Not Working --- */
}
.zoom-container.open .zoom {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0em;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 10px 30px, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 0px 25px;
}
```

There isn't anything I have that's writing it over but its still not displaying correctly.

You can see this in use here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/8H7hR/34/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the CSS `background: rgba(0,0,0,0,0.5); /* <--- Not Working --- */` is not working because that's invalid CSS3 should be `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` 
Notice the missing `0` you had 1 too many. **R** ed, **G** reen, **B** lue, **A** lpha transparency. :]

Comment: Oh yeah and an accept on the answer would be nice if this solves your problem ;]

Comment: and an upvote on my 1 sec late answer would be nice from you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have too many parameters in the statement that is not working (you have 5 when there should only be four):

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```